# Vlookup [By matching lookup value to half of the table array]

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have two sheets and one sheet has parent company name and another sheet has company name followed by product name. I want to do vlookup in product name to get matching company name inside product name option.
For example: Company name is apple and product name is apple macbook. Product name(apple macbook) matching company name(apple) I want to put apple before apple macbook column. [Company_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUGKa.png)
[Product_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db0LW.png)

I try to do find and match but couldn't do it. I am keen to learn if there is any method do to so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XLOOKUP(lookup_value, lookup_array, return_array,, [match_mode])` (or equivalent `VLOOKUP`)  with approximate `match_mode` set to `-1`, which means: exact match. If none found, return the next smaller item.

In cell `C2` use the following formula:

```
=XLOOKUP(D2:D7,$A$2:$A$4,$A$2:$A$4,,-1)
```

here is the output:

[image: sample output file]

or you can use exact match assuming the company name is at the beginning, so

```
=XLOOKUP(TEXTBEFORE(D2:D7, " "),$A$2:$A$4,$A$2:$A$4,"Not found")
```

This option gives you the possibility to check if the company name was not found.

**Note**: Both options are case insensitive.